# Multiple files in C++/QT drives me crazy

Tags: c++, qt4, window

When compiling my project, I get the error:

> Error: D:\Programming\Projects\Aprovado\examwindow.cpp:6: error:
>   invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::ExamWindow'

But there isn't anything wrong with that. Here's the line:

> ExamWindow::ExamWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new
>   Ui::ExamWindow)

The files: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2181407/damn.rar

Well, using QT4 with the follow files in the project: main.cpp, mainwindow.cpp, studywindow.cpp, mainwindow.h, studywindow.h, ui_mainwindow.h, ui_study.h, it works fiiine.
When I try to add the rest of the files it starts outputing errors.

I tried, I tried, I tried, and I cannot get out of it.

Could you guys help me out?

Comment: What errors, specifically?  Please produce a [**minimal** test-case](http://sscce.org), and then post the code here.

Comment: @user1282910: Please note StackOverflow is *not* meant for us to debug your compiler errors. You should rephrase the question to instead ask how to solve specific errors, which you make zero mention of your question. Asking a question in the format of "When I do X it doesn't work" explains nothing to us. Please include what errors occurred.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry. Rephrasing the question:
Error: D:\Programming\Projects\Aprovado\examwindow.cpp:6: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Ui::ExamWindow'

Buuut, there isn't anything wrong with that. Here's the line: ExamWindow::ExamWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      ui(new Ui::ExamWindow)
{

Like I said, with "two windows" it works correctly. When I try to add something more, it stops working giving me the output shown above.

Comment: I got something more. It's working JUST two files, when I try to add more files in the same way that I did with the first one, I get the error.

Comment: So this is an exam problem (homework?)

Comment: It's not what it looks like. I wouldn't make you guys solve my homework problems. Even because I wouldn't need that, since homeworks are kid stuff.
What I'm asking you guys to help me solve, it's a project that I'm doing for study the Qt Architecture and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `ui_examcalendar.h` is the right UI generated header for the `ExamWindow` class, you should change the name of the top level widget in the designer for the file `ExamCalendar.ui`

Currently, it is named `Form` so the generated UI class name is `Ui::Form`, so if you want `Ui::ExamWindow`, it should be named `ExamWindow`.

Comment: Should I be embarassed about this? Thanks, you solved my problem. Thanks man.

Comment: I cursed at myself. It was that easy. I renamed the form.

Answer (score 4):

You sound pretty desperate so I decided to download your code and take a look.

I encountered a number of issues. You did not include the `.ui` files so I was limited to how far I could go. Going past that was a compile error for `examwindow.cpp` that contained `Ui(new Ui::ExamWindow)` which should be `ui(new Ui::ExamWindow)`.

After that I got an error for invalid use of incomplete type `Ui::ExamWindow`. I noticed at that point that the second include was for `ui_examcalendar.h` That's not right. There should be an include for `ui_examwindow.h` but that file doesn't exist in your archive.

I gave up after that, sorry.

**After checking your updated files:**

As noted by @alexisdm, you have some naming issues. I got everything compiling by just doing some wholesale renaming to make everything consistent.

- Rename all files to lowercase equivalents of your `.cpp` files.
- Open each `.ui` file in the design editor and set the object name to the camel case equivalent of each `.cpp` file (ExamWindow, MainWindow, etc.)
- Make sure all the .cpp files are including the correct renamed filenames.

Comment: Man, I'm thankful for what you did, downloading my code and trying to figure out what the heck happened with that. And I am desperate, I'm too ansious with things.
Anyway, it turns out the file ui_examcalendar.h is actually the ui_examwindow you were looking for. Changing the names of the files and trying to make more sense in it, resulted in this, i'm sorry.

I really appreciated that you looked up my code.
I fixed it now. It includes all the .ui files and the repective examwindow ui header. 
If you don't wanna take a look at it now, I'll undestand. Thanks for you patient man.